# How to implement FlowRecordRelation with an LWC launched flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, relationships, record

My LWC launches a flow, and the user has the option to pause the flow.

If the flow is paused and the user navigates away and comes back to the page, there is the option to resume the flow.

The only issue is that my stand-in Apex query to return the correct flow interview was just a simple function to get all paused flow interviews and return the most recent one started by the current user. This works fine for testing my other functionalities, but now I need it to return the correct flow, specific to each record.

```
List<FlowInterview> interviews = 
    [ 
    SELECT Id FROM FlowInterview WHERE 
    CreatedById = :currentUser
    ];
    System.debug('Interviews: ' + interviews );
    if (interviews == null || interviews.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
return interviews.get(0).Id;
```

In my LWC it is easy to get the recordID, but as far as I'm aware, there is no field on the FlowInterview object to relate to the recordID. This is why I am attempting to use the FlowRecordRelation.

How would I do this. In the SF documentation it simply lists the fields and says that salesforce uses the global record variable to associate the record with the flow when the flow is paused, but my queries for FlowRecordRelation always return empty.

Do I need to instantiate a FlowRecordRelation in the LWC or the Apex or something?